# Unable to import NineOldAndroids in eclispse

Tags: android, nineoldandroids

where can i download the "**NineOldAndroids**" and how to import it in eclipse. when i am trying to import it , i am getting a message "No projects are found to import". Can someone show me how to import it?

Comment: Firstly, if you're just starting with Android development, download Android Studio and use that instead. You will have a much easier time compared to Eclipse.

Comment: Secondly, to use NineOldAndroids library, add the dependency 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In eclipse to import the NineOldAndroid we just need a jar file which you can download by clicking [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d1eh3zilkwxue51/NineOldAndroid-2.4.0.jar?dl=0) and download the jar and place it in your lib folder of your project and then

Step 1 - press  Alt+enter and Go to Java build path.

Step 2 - click on Add Jar and add the jar file.

Step 3 - Click on export and order and check the jar file and click on ok.

For more reference see the images

[image]

I Hope this will help you..Happeee programming!!!!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio users can do this -

download the jar file from here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/d1eh3zilkwxue51/NineOldAndroid-2.4.0.jar?dl=0

and place it in your project /libs folder

then go to: File - Project Structure - Dependencies - (click + to add)
then select "File Dependency" 
select libs/NineOldAndroid-2.4.0.jar and click OK

add to your class that uses it:
import com.nineoldandroids.(whateveryouneed);